# Quasi xml extracting text bewtween 2 start tags

Tags: python, regex, pdf-scraping

I've scraped some data from a pdf. It has data thats almost like XML and looks something like this
`"(1) Data-field-1 (3) Data-field-3 (5) Data-field-5; (1) Data-field-1 (2) Data-field-2 (3) Data-field-3 (5) Data-field-5; ; (2) Data-field-2 (3) Data-field-3 (5) Data-field-5 (6) Data-field-6;"` etc

So for each entry, the data field starts with (x). Usually, the entry ends with a semi-colon(;) but there is often semi-colons in the data field so I can't use it as a delimiter. The only indicator that a new record has started is that the integer in the start tag is less than the previous ones. Tags are from 1 to 6. I'd like to try and get a dictionary of dictionaries out so looks similar to JSON e.g.

`{'Row1':{1 : 'Data-field-1', 3 : 'Data-field-3', 5 : 'Data-field-5'},'Row2': {1: 'Data-field-1', 2: 'Data-field-2', 3: 'Data-field-3' 5: 'Data-field-5'},Row3': { 2: 'Data-field-2' ,3: 'Data-field-3' ,5: 'Data-field-5',6: 'Data-field-6'}`,etc

Trying to use regex in python to do this this is my last piece of code
for match in matches:

```
inner_dict={}
    test=filter(None, re.split(";", match))
    print test
    for i,x in enumerate(test):
        if i==0 :
            inner_dict[1]=x
        else:
            y=re.findall('\((\d)\)',x)[0]
            inner_dict[y]=re.findall('\(\d\)\s(.+)',x)[0]
    outer_dict[n]=inner_dict
    n+=1
```

but just getting trace back error (list index out of range) because of the extra semi-colons in the data fields
Any ideas of how to do it better?

Answer (score 0):

I would write a parser first and read this raw data item for item and then I would decide what to do with the item:

(1) Data-field-1 
-> First item --> create new entry in dict and append...

(3) Data-field-3 
-> Next item --> append at entry

(5) Data-field-5; 
-> Next item --> append at entry

(1) Data-field-1 
-> Next item = new line --> create a new entry and append...

Maybe this helps...